# Status bar style bug with UIImagePickerController

Tags: ios, objective-c, statusbar

I have my view controllers with the `[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarStyle:UIStatusBarStyleLightContent];` method in AppDelegate.m. and ViewController based status bar apparence to "NO" in plist.

All works fine, but at a moment in app, user have to take picture or browse one from the library, and all works fine at that stage.

[image]

But after picking the image in the library, the status bar come back to black color and that the same for the followings view controllers...

[image]

Does anyone could help me for this ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had the same problem days before, in the view controller you are returning to after you have selected the photo, in `viewWillAppear` method, try to add the following code.

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarStyle:UIStatusBarStyleLightContent];
[self setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate];
```

Answer (score 0):

It works like a charm for swift3 write in `viewWillAppear` :

```
func navigationController(_ navigationController: UINavigationController, willShow viewController: UIViewController, animated: Bool) {

        UIApplication.shared.setStatusBarStyle(.lightContent, animated: false)
    }
```